How to set a breakpoint at arm64 kernel startup entry point using QEMU and GDB
I want to set a breakpoint at the kernel startup entry point. It's an ARM64 QEMU setup, here is the command line of QEMU:
 qemu-system-aarch64 \
 -drive file=./build/tmp/deploy/images/qemu-arm64/demo-image-jailhouse-demo-qemu-arm64.ext4.img,discard=unmap,if=none,id=disk,format=raw \
 -m 1G \
 -serial mon:stdio \
 -netdev user,id=net \
 -kernel  /home/alan/Code/linux-6.1.90/out/arch/arm64/boot/Image \
 -append "root=/dev/vda mem=768M nokaslr" \
 -initrd ./build/tmp/deploy/images/qemu-arm64/demo-image-jailhouse-demo-qemu-arm64-initrd.img \
 -cpu cortex-a53 \
 -smp 16 \
 -machine virt,gic-version=3,virtualization=on,its=off \
 -device virtio-serial-device \
 -device virtconsole,chardev=con \
 -chardev vc,id=con \
 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=disk \
 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net \
 -gdb tcp::1234 -S

I want to break the kernel in file arch/arm64/kernel/head.S at the entry point.
I understand that a Physical address should be given to the gdb as MMU is not yet enabled at startup. So what is the physical address I should use, is the address of kernel code that can be found in /proc/iomem?
# cat /proc/iomem 
00000000-03ffffff : 0.flash flash@0
04000000-07ffffff : 0.flash flash@0
08000000-0800ffff : GICD
080a0000-08ffffff : GICR
09000000-09000fff : pl011@9000000
  09000000-09000fff : 9000000.pl011 pl011@9000000
09010000-09010fff : pl031@9010000
  09010000-09010fff : rtc-pl031
09030000-09030fff : pl061@9030000
  09030000-09030fff : 9030000.pl061 pl061@9030000
0a003a00-0a003bff : a003a00.virtio_mmio virtio_mmio@a003a00
0a003c00-0a003dff : a003c00.virtio_mmio virtio_mmio@a003c00
0a003e00-0a003fff : a003e00.virtio_mmio virtio_mmio@a003e00
10000000-3efeffff : pcie@10000000
40000000-6fffffff : System RAM
  40210000-41b0ffff : Kernel code
  41b10000-4226ffff : reserved
  42270000-426bffff : Kernel data
  48000000-483f0fff : reserved
  48400000-484fffff : reserved
  6cf30000-6fdfffff : reserved
  6fe59000-6fe5afff : reserved
  6fe5b000-6fe5bfff : reserved
  6fe5c000-6fe6ffff : reserved
  6fe70000-6fe7dfff : reserved
  6fe7e000-6fffffff : reserved
4010000000-401fffffff : PCI ECAM
8000000000-ffffffffff : pcie@10000000

I've tried with following method, but not working.
Launch gdb:
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gdb vmlinux

In gdb:
b *0x40210000
target remote :1234
c

What should I do?
PS. I can stop at start_kernel() function, so my gdb setting are good I think.

The physical address is build with the kernel. On top of that you should be aware of the compression and relocation. You really need to study that assembly code that is used there for earliest stages of booting kernel. Also, note that there are different entry points into the kernel depending on the system and bootloader (in your case it's QEMU and you should study documentation as well to get what QEMU uses as an entry point for the emulated HW in question).

I've found a solution to the question. Since MMU was not enabled at the early stage, we have to break at the physical address. But what's the right starting address(PA)? Inspired by 0andriy, I found out that the physical address of the entry point is 0x40200000(depending on the different bootloader QEMU in my case). Instead of loading vmlinux with gdb, I'm using add-symbol-file to vmlinux and specifying the section name and its corresponding physical address.
add-symbol-file vmlinux -s .head.text 0x40200000 -s .text 0x40210000

Then b _text, _text is the entry point of the kernel by looking at the file vmlinux.lds.S
After this gdb can stop at the first line of the kernel:
(gdb) add-symbol-file vmlinux -s .head.text 0x40200000 -s .text 0x40210000
add symbol table from file "vmlinux" at
        .head.text_addr = 0x40200000
        .text_addr = 0x40210000
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from vmlinux...
(gdb) b _text
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40200000: file ../arch/arm64/kernel/head.S, line 60.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, _text () at ../arch/arm64/kernel/head.S:60
60              efi_signature_nop                       // special NOP to identity as PE/COFF executable
(gdb) n
61              b       primary_entry                   // branch to kernel start, magic
(gdb) 
89              bl      preserve_boot_args
(gdb) n

